# Pandas - Return first item in dataframe, grouped by user

Tags: python, pandas

I have a lot of user/item/timestamp data. I want to know which items were consumed first, second third, etc. by all users.

My questions are: if I have a dataframe that is already sorted by time (descending), will it stay sorted by default through the `groupby` process? and, how can I pull out the first two items consumed by any user, even if the user has not consumed two items?

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'item_id': ['b', 'b', 'a', 'c', 'a', 'b'], 'user_id': [1,2,1,1,3,1], 'time': range(6)})

print df
pd.get_dummies(df['item_id'])

gp = df.groupby('user_id').head()
print gp

# Return item_id of first one installed in each case ??
```

This gives:

```
  item_id  time  user_id
0       b     0        1
1       b     1        2
2       a     2        1
3       c     3        1
4       a     4        3
5       b     5        1

          item_id  time  user_id
user_id                         
1       0       b     0        1
        2       a     2        1
        3       c     3        1
        5       b     5        1
2       1       b     1        2
3       4       a     4        3
```

Now, I need to pull out the top two item_id values, something like this (but retaining the user_id column is not essential):

```
user_id    order    item_id
      1        0          b
      1        1          a
      2        0          b
      3        0          a
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a hack:

```
In [75]: def nth_order(x, n):
   ....:     xn = x[:n]
   ....:     return xn.join(Series(arange(len(xn)), name='order', index=xn.index))
   ....:

In [76]: df.groupby('user_id').apply(lambda x: nth_order(x, 2))
Out[76]:
          item_id  time  user_id  order
user_id
1       0       b     0        1      0
        2       a     2        1      1
2       1       b     1        2      0
3       4       a     4        3      0
```

Note that you can't just use `n`, because you may have a group where `len(group) < 2`, therefore

`len(x[:n]) != n`

in every case (as per your question).

This is a feature of this particular kind of slicing in pandas: if you slice pass the end here you'll just get every row (and there may not be `n` rows), whereas with [`iloc` indexing](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/indexing.html#indexing-integer), that isn't true. That is, an exception will be raised if you try to slice past the end of the array.

Comment: The order column from a groupby is a popular request/task, I can't recall if I've created an issue for it before.

Comment: Good to know! Definitely useful.

Comment: Wow, with all that Pandas does, it's surprising that this case hasn't already been covered. @AndyHaden & Phillip Cloud, thanks so much for the help!

Answer (score 2):

You can do this directly with [head](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.head.html) which gets the top `n` results):

```
In [11]: g = df.groupby('user_id')

In [12]: g.head(2)
Out[12]:
          item_id  time  user_id
user_id
1       0       b     0        1
        2       a     2        1
2       1       b     1        2
3       4       a     4        3
```

As of 0.13 IIRC, this is *much* faster than any apply-based solution head (calling head used to be a fallthrough to `.apply(lambda x: x.head())`.

*The implementation uses `cumcount` so is similar in spirit to PhilipCloud's solution.*

Comment: You can actually call `g.head(2)` as well.

Comment: I wonder if something like `df.groupby('spam').apply(make_spam_green, order=True)` would be the way to do this...

Comment: One *potential* bug is if make_spam_green takes order as a kwarg.

Comment: Good point. Maybe I should actually learn to use pandas correctly before making suggestions about APIs :P

Comment: I thought using `as_index=False` ought to mean `user_id` wasn't in the index, it doesn't...

Comment: Looks like a bug in `head`

Comment: It's also present in apply though (with both our answers). ?

Comment: Yep but different methods result in no index with `as_index=False`. Try `df.groupby('user_id', as_index=False).sum()`.

Comment: @BenLiyanage Note I subsequently made this much faster in pandas (with the help of cumcount), so it should be **significantly** faster than any apply-based solution.